# hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files not working

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I want to perform initial data loading with spring mvc and hibernate4. the given code will generate all the tables, but it didn't import files.
[image]

[image]

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/WEB-INF/indexes</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">hrms.sql</prop>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that just the paths are wrong. Please try to:

- put your (.csv's + .sql) files into (!`src/main/`)`resources` (folder).

..or alternatively:

- refer to all csv files as "**WEB-INF/**[xyz]**.csv**", AND:

  - refer to "WEB-INF/hrms.sql" (in your spring/hibernate config file).
    OR
  - move it (`hrms.sql`) also to (!`src/main/`)`resources`.

Comment: Yeah! I moved all the files(.csv+.sql) to resources folder, but it didn't taking the .csv files. If I add a direct insert query, that will work here.